# Are `list` and `listitem` ARIA roles appropriate for a <table>?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am wondering if a table representing a list of items should or could also be decorated with ARIA roles, or the semantic of a table is enough.

This is a basic example of something I am working on:

```
<table role="list" aria-labelledby="caption">
    <caption id="caption">Opening hours</caption>
    <tr role="listitem"><td>Sunday</td><td>10am - 8pm</td></tr>
    <tr role="listitem"><td>Monday</td><td>10am - 8pm</td></tr>
    <tr role="listitem"><td>Friday</td><td>10am - 8pm</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am still a bit confused about the slightly overlapping of aria and html5 semantic.

**Updated example**

I am thinking about something along these lines, now

```
<table role="presentation">
    <caption id="oh-caption">Opening hours</caption>
    <tbody role="list" aria-describedby="oh-caption">
        <tr role="listitem">
            <td>...</td>
        <tr role="listitem">
            <td>...</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you are presenting is in fact a data table and you should just mark it up with the appropriate markup to associate the row headers correctly. The reason you can tell its a data table is the fact that the data in the second column is associated with the data in the first column and each column contains data of the same type (if it were a complex data table these simple rules would need to be expanded).

```
<table>
    <caption>Opening hours</caption>
    <tr><th scope="row">Sunday</th><td>10am - 8pm</td></tr>
    <tr><th scope="row">Monday</th><td>10am - 8pm</td></tr>
    <tr><th scope="row">Friday</th><td>10am - 8pm</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, of course, this is why I opted for a table element instead of a simple UL in the first place. But I was thinking about overriding the semantic of this table to _also_ convey the information that this is, in fact, the _list of opening hours_ for the restaurant.

Comment: The markup in this example is perfect (don't forget to use the th element!). A person with disabilities gets all necessary information. Why do you want to add the information, that the data table containing the opening hours is also a list? I think this does not add any value for the user.

Comment: @chaenu yep, that's exactly the gist of my question: I am adding some information or not? :) The problem is that it seems "difficult" to find a square answer to that question.

Comment: elements can only have one role at a time. If you add a role attribute it REPLACES the implicit role. You are making the accessibility worse if you do this, not better.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go trough your example:

```
<table role="presentation">
  <caption id="oh-caption">Opening hours</caption>
  <tbody role="list" aria-describedby="oh-caption">
    <tr role="listitem">
        <td>...</td>
    <tr role="listitem">
        <td>...</td>
</tbody>
```

First [role="presentation"] negates the implicit "table" semantics. This includes also the implicit native semantics of its tbody/tr/... descendants, as they will also be removed. So basically this is what the user agent now "sees":

```
<span>
  <span id="oh-caption">Opening hours</span>
  <span role="list" aria-describedby="oh-caption">
    <span role="listitem">
        <span>...</span>
    <span role="listitem">
        <span>...</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

You are not enhancing the semantics of a table, you are deleting them. Read more about [role="presentation"] in the [wai-aria specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#presentation).

Next [role="list"] and [role="listitem"], which generates a group of list items:

```
<span>
  <span id="oh-caption">Opening hours</span>
  <ul aria-describedby="oh-caption">
    <li>
        <span>...</span>
    <li>
        <span>...</span>
  </ul>
</span>
```

There's aria-describedby="oh-caption" left, which references to the #oh-caption element as a label.

The screenreader would now announce a list with 2 items, labelled as "Opening hours". But you lost the connection between the caption of the row ("Monday") and the related opening hours, because you simplified the content structure. Also a user cannot "read" only the opening hours without the connected days, which he could in a semantic table by "jumping" vertically from table cell to table cell. (Probably he knows already that you're open 7 days a week and does only want to know if you close one day earlier than 8pm.)

Therefore I personally do not see an advantage of this transformation and suggest using the semantic markup provided by @unobf. Keep also future changes in mind. What would you do, if you had to add another column, because they close at noon and want to display the opening hours for morning and afternoon in separate columns?

Comment: Thank you, I am definitely convinced now. I will accept @unobf answer though, if you don't mind, because it came first and solves my problem (I will use that markup indeed).